# Quarkus - Pushing Micrometer metrics to prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, quarkus, micrometer

I have gone through the guide at https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer. I want to capture a basic metric telling me how many times a particular endpoint is called, and have used `MeterRegistry` for my purpose.

```
registry.counter("request").increment();
```

I am able to see this metric at http://localhost:8080/hello/q/metrics. Now I want to push this metric to prometheus, but I haven't been able to find any guide for that, which shows how to register/integrate the metrics with prometheus. Ideally, I would like to push them to graphite, but that isn't supported. So I would like to know how to push these metrics so I can visualise them in Grafana.

Comment: With Prometheus you don't push, you pull. You need to configure a scrape point: [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config)

Comment: What did you mean that you would like to push to graphite not being supported?

Comment: Maybe pushing via Graphite protocol to VictoriaMetrics is what you want? See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-send-data-from-graphite-compatible-agents-such-as-statsd). The pushed data then can be queried via [Prometheus datasource in Grafana](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#grafana-setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things (integrating also comments above).

Out of the box (unless you turn them off), all endpoint requests are already measured using a timer called "http.server.requests", as noted in the guide here: https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer#review-automatically-generated-metrics. If you look at prometheus output (using the `/q/metrics` endpoint), you will see `http_server_requests_seconds_count` indicating how many times your endpoint has been invoked (the URL is in a tag).

There is a graphite extension in Quarkiverse. Add the graphite extension to your pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.micrometer.registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-graphite</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And update the quarkus configuration in application.properties as described in the docs: https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-micrometer-registry/dev/micrometer-registry-graphite.html